# A slight variation of the Ricker model

Tags: mathematical-modeling, biology

Suppose you are modelling a population of a single species at a time $t$,  $N_t$. But to make it slightly simpler you want to explore $\hat{N_t}$, which is defined by $\hat{N_t} = \frac{N_t}{K}$ where $K$ is the carrying capacity of the population.

The Ricker model has the standard equation

$N_{t+1} = N_te^{r\left({1 - \frac{N_t}{k}}\right)}$

Which using $\hat{N_t}$ becomes

$\hat{N}_{t+1} = \hat{N}_te^{r\left(1 - \hat{N_t}\right)}$.

However the variation of this that I am looking at is

$\hat{N}_{t+1} = \hat{N}_te^{r\left(1 - \hat{N_t}\right)} + Q$.

What is the meaning of Q here and how does this affect population growth over time?

Comment: The quantity $Q$ may represent a constant immigration, that is, the fact that, at each time step, $QK$ new individuals are added to the population $N$. This modifies the fixed point $\hat N_*=1$ for $Q=0$ to some value $\hat N_*>1$ solving the equation $\hat N_*\exp(r(1-\hat N_*))+Q=\hat N_*$.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me find this which anyone else who sees this might find useful: http://132.66.16.6/lifesci/departments/zoology/members/stone/documents/effectsofimmigrationon...pdf